# Passing json request to sitewhere server

Tags: json, web-services, remote-server

hello all i am trying to pass the json device registration request to remote sitewhere(IoT server) via external .NET application. Following is my code

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
```

namespace Sitewhere_connect
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(@"http://localhost:1883/SiteWhere/input/json");
        req.Method = "POST";
        // Create Client
        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        // Assign Credentials
        client.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("admin", "password", "sitewhere1234567890");
        req.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        using (var streamWriter = new StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream()))
        {
            string json = "{\"hardwareId\":\"123456789\"," +
                          "\"siteToken\":\"bb105f8d-3150-41f5-b9d1-db04965668d3\"," +
                          "\"specificationToken\":\"82043707-9e3d-441f-bdcc-33cf0f4f7260\"," +
                          "\"comments\":\"Equipment tracker.\" }";
            streamWriter.Write(json);
            streamWriter.Flush();
            streamWriter.Close();

        }
        try
        {
            var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();
            using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
            {
                var result = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            }
        }
        catch (System.Exception excep)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(excep.Message);

        }

    }
}
```

}

Comment: define the issue u r facing exactly

Comment: i got solution for this issue. Resolved

Comment: than u can post ur answer too..!!! Its free